# What is this component? Marked 'M3 36 t' (Case: SOT-23-6)

Tags: identification, sot23

Help me identify the component on the board labeled **M3 36 t** .

I have a Siemens KTP600 HMI under repair (reason: it does not turn on). I found that an element was missing on the board (highlighted in a red circle). After inspecting the working board of the same HMI, I found out that there should be an element marked 'M3 36 t' (highlighted in a yellow circle). But I couldn't find this element by marking.

[image]

Marking: **M3 36 t**
Case: **SOT-23-6** or **TSOT-23-6**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [PBSS4240DPN](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PBSS4240DPN.pdf) (SOT457 in reality) from NXP/Nexperia. Marking code "M3".

36 is the datecode, t is the assembly location code.

[picture from LCSC](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Nexperia-PBSS4240DPN115/C503568)
[image: picture from LCSC]